# Google API userRequestsExceededRateLimit for YouTube Streaming

Tags: python, google-api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I hit the following error while experimenting with the YouTube Data API v3 (in python)

```
{
    "message": "User requests exceed the rate limit.",
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "userRequestsExceedRateLimit"
}
```

When I look at my metrics I see the following:

| Method | Requests |
| --- | --- |
| `youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveBroadcastService.Bind` | 5 |
| `youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveBroadcastService.Insert` | 43 |
| `youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveStreamService.Insert` | 14 |

These values seem ... pretty low to me.
Additionally, when I go to the "Quotas" tab the graph for `Quota exceeded errors count (1 min) - Queries per minute` shows no data.

Further confusing the issue is the "[YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)". It has a nebulous "Cost" column. Am I going over on cost somehow? Where is "cost" defined?

This is my first time working with google APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error [`userRequestsExceedRateLimit`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert-rateLimitExceeded-userBroadcastsExceedLimit) on the  [`LiveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) API endpoint has the following meaning: you've issued too many calls to that API endpoint *in a short amount of time*:

> **`rateLimitExceeded`** **`userRequestsExceedRateLimit`**
> The user has sent too many requests in a given timeframe.

Unfortunately, that time threshold is not mentioned at all within the official documents.

In any case, you should expect that your API calls to work OK after certain (unspecified) amount of time.